# mapViewWillStartLoadingMap method does not called second time Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Map Kit View. mapViewWillStartLoadingMap method  called  when I navigate MapViewController first time. Then I go back previous controller and again navigate MapViewController , mapViewWillStartLoadingMap not called. Where is my mistake  ?

I am using this method go to previous controller from MapViewController

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your ViewController containing the map is being deInitialised.

Add this to your VC and set a breakpoint on it.

```
deinit {

}
```

If its not that, check the delegate for the map view is set correctly when your map VC is on active.

Comment: go into deinit methods.